# Zenoss, Not able to understand use of data values

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, zenoss

I am working on a project in which we are monitoring data of some virtual devices which is running on zenoss server , I get the actual data by calling several api's lets suppose calling on some url which ends with /getRRDInfoTabDevice gives value of data store and data point, then i again make call using this values and i get data in xml which is as follows

```
<row><t>2147483700</t><v0>1.8917126005e-305</v0></row>
```

where t is data for time, and v0 is actual data, so my question is what is the use of this value v0, as one can see its in e-305 which is almost near to zero ?

Comment: The value is going to be the rate per-second of whatever you're measuring for the time window based at that time.  As to what use it is, that's up to you and whatever the value is for! Not knowing how you obtain the original source data how can we say?
A value that low seems to be close the the virtual -INF value though.

Comment: Actually i am measuring the cpu utilisation of one of the virtual machine and when i am calling api's to fetch data from rrd file then i am getting these kind of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is in octet /second , this value is used to monitor cpu utilization , network utilization etc. It basically depends on what you are monitoring through your rrdtool.